# Are these monadic expressions equivalent

Tags: haskell, monads

I come across some short piece of monadic code and I have a question not related to the actual subject of the example

```
ap :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap mf mx = do
        f <- mf
        x <- mx
        return (f x)
```

staying purely symbolic without knowing at all the context or what the code "does", is the above equivalent to

```
ap :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap mf mx = do
        x <- mx
        f <- mf
        return (f x)
```

When I had first seen the example code I had wondered if there was a reason wether the author of this code has chosen the order f <- mf, x <-mx over x <- mx, f <- mf consciously because the order does make a difference or entirely arbitrarily.

Best regards

Günther

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent. Desugared, they are

```
mf >>= (\f -> mx >>= (\x -> return (f x)))
mx >>= (\x -> mf >>= (\f -> return (f x)))
```

So the bind operation is applied to `mf` first, `mx` second in the first definition and the other way around in the second. Bind is not commutative, or at least it does not need to be (it's not required by the monad laws). A counterexample that doesn't involve IO is `mf = [(+1), (+2)]`, `mx = [1, 5]`.

Answer (score 4):

A simple example where they aren't the same (in that they have different side effects):

```
mf :: IO (Int -> Int)
mf = do
    putStr "Hello, "
    return (+1)

mx :: IO Int
mx = do
    putStr "world"
    return 1

ap1 = Control.Monad.ap
ap2 mf mx = do
    x <- mx
    f <- mf
    return (f x)
```

And to test it out

```
> void $ ap1 mf mx
Hello, world
> void $ ap2 mf mx
worldHello,
```

These are obviously quite different results even though the actual result of the computation is the same in both cases, i.e. 2.

Comment: Hi bheklir, yeah I thought about IO too, but technically I do not know wether there are acutally guarantees in which order IO occurs in Haskell and second the "return" value is still the same, i.e. IO (). So thus, staying purely symbolically, is there a difference, symbolically?

Comment: @Günni If we weren't guaranteed that IO actions would happen in a particular order, then we wouldn't use Haskell.  No matter what optimizations the compiler does, it _can not_ reorder monadic operations, that is one of the fundamental points to having monads.  It _can_ reorder applicative actions, and this can be used to great effect in libraries like Haxl.  Another good example is the one given by delnan, where the return value is quite different depending on which definition you use, and this is without side effects at all.

Comment: Hm, probably it could reorder monadic operations if it proved they were commutative. It's just that most monadic operations aren't, so it doesn't.

Comment: @ThomasAhle The problem is that it can't be proved for just "monadic computations", but it could be proved for, say, the `Maybe` monad.  The monad constraint is not strong enough by itself, you need other properties for it to work.  So in general, the compiler does not have the ability to reorder monadic operations, but maybe it can reorder operations if more is known about a particular instance of `Monad`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, IO is a simple counterexample. The list monad is not commutative, also.

```
Prelude> do f<-[succ,pred] ; x<-[10,20] ; return (f x)
[11,21,9,19]
Prelude> do x<-[10,20] ; f<-[succ,pred] ; return (f x)
[11,9,21,19]
```

Let's build a little list of commutative monads.

**Commutative**:

- Identity
- Reader / `(->) a`
- Maybe
- Cont (I guess?)
- [] (if you disregard order)
- Random (at least morally)
- UniqueSupply (at least morally)

**Non commutative**:

- Writer
- State
- IO / ST
- STM
- [] (if order matters)
- Either
- Random (formally)
- UniqueSupply (formally)

Comment: `Either` is not commutative – it returns the first `Left` in the chain.

Comment: list monad can be seen "morally" commutative too, as we're supposed to ignore order when interpreting lists as non-deterministic values.

Answer (score 0):

This question actually has answers at two levels:

1. Are the two expressions equivalent *from the point of view of the monad laws*.
2. Are the two expressions equivalent *from the point of view of a specific monad*.

The thing to understand is this: any type that instantiates `Monad` is required to obey the [monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws), which demand that certain expressions be equivalent (e.g., `(a >> b) >> c == a >> (b >> c)`).  But the monad laws do not *forbid* individual monads from having additional equivalences.

The monad laws in and of themselves do not require your two functions to be equivalent; therefore:

- There are some specific monads where your two functions are equivalent, and others where they are not.
- If you're writing code that's supposed to work for any arbitrary monad, you may not assume the equivalence.

On the other hand, several monads do make your functions equivalent; for example, `Maybe` and `Reader` do.  A monad that obeys that equivalence is called a **commutative** monad—one where the order of effects does not matter.